# Genesis Framework: How to exclude a specific author from archive custom loop

Tags: functions, loop, genesis-theme-framework

I am using the Genesis Framework on my website, and have added the following code to my functions.php to customize the archive loop.

```
//* Archive Custom Loop
function archive_custom_loop() {

    echo '<div class="archive-pagination">';

next_posts_link('<div class="proigoumeno">Previous Posts &raquo;</div>', $loop ->max_num_pages);
previous_posts_link('<div class="epomeno">&laquo; Newer Posts</div>', $loop ->max_num_pages);

    echo '</div>';

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ?>

<div class="lista"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank" style="font-weight: 700;"><?php the_title() ?></a><br><p class="entry-meta"><span class="entry-author"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span><span class="provoles"><?php do_action( 'pageviews' ); ?> <img src="https://www.pcsteps.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/views.png" alt="Views"></span><span class="imerominia">Posted: <?php the_date() ?></span></p></div>

<div class="eikona"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(360, 200) ); ?></a></div>

<div class="perilipsi"><?php $content = get_the_excerpt(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 500, '...'); ?></div>

<div class="diaxwristiko"></div>

    <?php
    endwhile;

    echo '<div class="archive-pagination">';

next_posts_link('<div class="proigoumeno">Previous Posts &raquo;</div>', $loop ->max_num_pages);
previous_posts_link('<div class="epomeno">&laquo; Newer Posts</div>', $loop ->max_num_pages);

    echo '</div">';

}
```

What I would like is to select one author ID, and completely exclude it from the archives.

I have read [the codex for the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Exclude_Posts_From_Some_Category), but the syntax is a bit different, and I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `pre_get_posts` hook. In WP_Query there is an `author` parameter : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters

`pre_get_posts` hook : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

```
function wpse_288986_remove_post_from_author($query) {
    // We have to check if we are in front and if the query is the main query
    if(!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_archive())
    {
        $query->set('author', -2); // Where 2 is your user ID
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse_288986_remove_post_from_author');
```

EDIT : This code goes into your `functions.php` file

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Is there a problem if I don't add the "!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()" part? the plain if(is_archive()) seems to work just fine.

Comment: `is_admin()` is for the posts list in your wp-admin, but it's not an archive page so yes, you can remove it. `is_main_query` is here to check if you're on the main query and not in another WP_Query. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query